# Oracle Index Timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-performance

**Scenario:**

I have a table with 568801 rows and an index on the column `TIM_RECEPT` (TIMESTAMP). The index is generated as `TRUNC("TIM_RECEPT")`.

This table was filled on 19 of April with this query:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE SELECT <fields> FROM <tables>
```

The next days the table has been loaded with:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE SELECT <fields> 
FROM <tables> WHERE alias.tim_recept > TRUNC(SYSDATE -1)
```

**Problem:**

When I use the index in explain plan, return this:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
select *
from  MY_TABLE
where trunc(TIM_RECEPT) >= TO_DATE('22/11/2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
    and trunc(TIM_RECEPT) <= TO_DATE('26/04/2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |           | 42112 |    13M|  8690   (1)| 00:01:45 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| MY_TABLE  | 42112 |    13M|  8690   (1)| 00:01:45 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IMYTABLE1 | 42112 |       |   114   (0)| 00:00:02 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access(TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("TIM_RECEPT"))>=TO_DATE(' 2017-11-22 
              00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
              TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("TIM_RECEPT"))<=TO_DATE(' 2018-04-26 00:00:00', 
              'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

**BUT** if I change the initial date and rest one day, the index is not used:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
select *
from  MY_TABLE
where trunc(TIM_RECEPT) >= TO_DATE('21/11/2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
    and trunc(TIM_RECEPT) <= TO_DATE('26/04/2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |          | 42395 |    14M|  8739   (1)| 00:01:45 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| MY_TABLE | 42395 |    14M|  8739   (1)| 00:01:45 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("TIM_RECEPT"))>=TO_DATE(' 
              2017-11-21 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
              TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("TIM_RECEPT"))<=TO_DATE(' 2018-04-26 00:00:00', 
              'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

Any idea about this issue?

Comment: I guess the optimiser is just deciding that the additional volume from the extra day - indicated here by the number of rows - has crossed a boundary where it's cheaper to do a full scan that use the index. Based on the stats it has, which may not be up-to-date (we don't know the date distribution - whether there are actually any rows for that extra day). It's not always helpful, but what cost is reported if you add a hint to use the index?

Comment: Does the plan change if you run `dbms_stats.gather_table_stats()` for that table?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you are specifying the format `'DD-MM-YYYY'` in your `to_date()` call, but you provide the date in `DD/MM/YYYY` format.

Comment: Why do you use trunc? It makes the index much less selective and hence less likely to be used. Your query where you check if the time is between two dates will work just as well without trunc.

Comment: @AlexPoole Using `select * /*+ INDEX(TIM_RECEPT) */ ` in explain plan I have the same results

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't have permissions to use `dbms_stats.gather_table_stats()` :/ About format, wrong copy paste... I changed it and result is the same

Comment: @ewramner I use trunc because the column is timestamp, and an index without trunc it is useless

Comment: @Alberto - that should have been `select /*+ INDEX(MY_TABLE IMYTABLE1) */ * from ...`. Incidentally, are you actually seeing a performance problem, or do both perform similarly and you're just curious? The optimiser may well be doing the right thing...

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for your notice. I have changed the hint, but the explain plan it's the same. I have performance issue

Comment: What's the difference in time taken for running these 2 queries?

Comment: I can't see why the index would be less useful without trunc. The only difference is that with trunc you can search for equality, but if you search for greater than, less than or between an index on the whole timestamp should perform just as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that Oracle optimizer doesn't use index i snot necessary *a problem*. It is a problem 
when the resources consumed (in most cases elapsed time) with the  `FULL TABLE SCAN` access is higher that an
alternative execution plan using `INDEX ACCESS` (which you not *explicitly* states).

Form the point of view of the optimizer, both execution plans are fine and lead to approximately same time.

So if the experience with those queries is different, and the actual elapsed time is highly different from the estimation (01:45)
you (or your DBA)) should take following steps:

**1) Verify Optimizer Statistics of the table**

Stale statistics may fool the optimizer. Especially in case you gather the statistics on a small table and
that inserts a large number of records.

**2) Verify optimizer parameters and System Statistics**

Some parameters notably [DB_FILE_MULTIBLOCK_READ_COUNT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-69E45087-14DF-492B-B55A-8F2E936947A5.htm#REFRN10037) are highly relevant for the selection between `FTS` and `INDEX ACCES`.

Similar is valid for [System Statistics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/tgsql/gathering-optimizer-statistics.html#GUID-69E0AEFD-5C03-4EB6-B3CC-CD07153759E6) setting.

**Final Remark**

To access a non-trivial parts of a large table (say 50 from 100 days) is not necessary a use case of `INDEX ACCESS`. Check the **partitioning feature**, which ([range partitioning](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-EAFD703C-EFA9-4819-85BD-79F63B761A96.htm#VLDBG1269))
is designed for this kind of access.